# How granular is the Balance skill?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-duel-links

Mako Tsunami gains a skill called "Balance" at level 20. The description for balance says "Your starting hand will reflect the card balance of your deck." What groupings does it use to determine card balance? Is it merely monsters/spells/traps, or does it place effect and ritual monsters into their own categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://duellinks.gamea.co/c/e678o2q2) guide, this is only affected by Monster, Spell, and Trap cards. It does not take sub-categories (i.e. Ritual/Fusion/Effect Monsters) into consideration

> **Rating and Explanation**
>
> Having ten monsters, five spells, and five traps in your deck, will make you get two monsters, one spell, and one trap card in your opening hand. It will make you draw a monster the next turn and then a spell, and then a trap. The cards in your hand will always reflect the ratio in your deck. This skill might have a huge potential on the PVP.